# Where is, if it exists, a repo's .git or .gitconfig file?

Tags: git, unity-game-engine

I'm following the [Unity 3D guide to enable SmartMerge in Git](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SmartMerge.html), but I'm quite confused. It literally says:

> Add the following text to your .git or .gitconfig file

but I don't have any in my repo. I know there is a `.gitconfig` file which is global for the whole Git installation, and thus it doesn't seem very logic as a place to put repo-specific settings, and `.git` is a folder in git repos, not a file.

Where do I have to put those lines?

Comment: `.git` is typically a hidden folder in the root of your repository. If you're using worktrees this gets muddled but I assume you're not there yet. `.gitconfig` is a file in your "home" directory, like C:\Users\USERNAME, or it can mean `config` which is located in the aforementioned `.git` folder.

Comment: I know it's a folder, that's why the mention of a .git file bugs me.

Comment: `.git` *can* be a file if you're using worktrees, it is then located in the root of the worktree and contains information about where the `.git` *folder* is located. This file should not be edited, however, so if you're supposed to add something to `.git` then it *has* to be the folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file where you should put those lines is actually `config` in the `.git` folder. Don't know why the Unity docs are so confusing about this.